# Accessing Site Newsfeed in Sharepoint 2013 via REST

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, rest, social

I have a SharePoint system set up and a site created named `'testsite'`. 
I can access folders and documents via different means respectively, e.g.:

```
http://host.name/testsite/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/testsite/shared%20documents')/folders
```

Now I would like to access the newsfeed for this site. 
As far as i understand the documentation (whick lacks examples) i should be able to do so using the following URL:

```
http://host.name/testsite/_api/social.feed/actor(item=@v)/feed?@v='http://host.name'/testsite/newsfeed.aspx
```

However I get the following response:

I don't have any indication of what i am doing wrong here. And would appreciate any sort of help.

Comment: what is the response you got?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have a ' after the .name in your v= parameter, remove that and you should get a good response. Try this

```
http://host.name/testsite/_api/social.feed/actor(item=@v)/feed?@v='http://host.name/testsite/newsfeed.aspx'
```